# error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel' inside dockerfile

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile, python-wheel

I am getting the following error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fisher, goatools, wget
  ...
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for fisher: finished with status 'error'
  ...

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for fisher
  Running setup.py clean for fisher
```

Inside the this Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch-backports
RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    apache2 \
    python-dev \
    python-setuptools \
    python-numpy \
    python-mysqldb \
    python-pip \
    git wget \
    ncbi-blast+ && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN pip install wheel fisher goatools
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is `RUN pip -V` and `RUN python -V`?

Comment: `RUN pip -V -> pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)` and 
` RUN python -V -> Python 2.7.13`

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I see it - you have to split the last command in two: `RUN pip install wheel` and `RUN pip install fisher goatools`. Or even better, install `python-wheel` with `apt-get` among other packages.

Comment: Thank you, python-wheel worked out

Answer (score 1):

Try to install `wheel` package first then everything else

```
RUN pip install wheel
RUN pip install fisher goatools
```